# Imprimir valores de um vetor sem quebra de linha

Tags: c#, array, .net, algoritmo

Olá, estou realizando um exercício em C# que pede o seguinte:

[image: Entrada e Saída que deve ser usada]

A saída com os números pares deve ser apresentada sem quebra de linha, porém não entendo como posso fazer isso. 
O meu código está assim:

```
int N;
        N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] numeros = new int[N];

        String[] entrada = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            numeros[i] = int.Parse(entrada[i]);
        }

        int quantidade;
        quantidade = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {

            if (numeros[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(numeros[i]);
                quantidade = quantidade + 1;
            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine(quantidade);
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 4):

Tem diversos problemas nesse código. Dei uma organizada e tornei o código mais idiomático para ir acostumando (não basta funcionar, precisa ir aprendendo como realmente se faz código em produção) e resolvi a maioria deles. Claro, nem todos darão erros óbvios, mas darão em certas situações.

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var n)) return;
        var numeros = new int[n];
        string[] entrada = ReadLine().Split(' ');
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (!int.TryParse(entrada[i], out var valor)) return;
            numeros[i] = valor;
        }
        var quantidade = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (numeros[i] % 2 == 0) {
                Write($"{numeros[i]} ");
                quantidade++;
            }
        }
        WriteLine();
        WriteLine(quantidade);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/TwLeAb). E [no **repl.it**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/giBE4f). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Algorithm/SplitAndPrint.cs).

Eu testei os valores antes de usar porque se a pessoa digitar algo errado a aplicação vai quebrar. Eu preferi só sair neste caso mas você poderia dar uma mensagem indicando o erro. Como exercício futuro pode fazer o dado ser pedido de novo em vez de encerrar a aplicação normalmente.

Pedir dados tudo em uma linha só é pedir para ter problema, inicialmente achei até que o exercício pedia isso e fiz assim, mas na verdade ele nem pede, ele apenas mostrou os dados que serão entrados. Da mesma forma que a saída não tem um formato específico, então se quebra linha ou não nem importa muito. Eu mudaria isso para ler cada dado individualmente.

De qualquer forma eu usei o `Write()` em vez do `WriteLine()` para não pular linha, mas dei uma espaço. Eu usei a interpolação neste casos para aprender a forma, mas na verdade nem é necessário em um caso tão simples, se fizer com concatenação está bom. Sem o espaço ficará tudo amontoado.

Note a quantidade menor de linhas sem prejudicar a legibilidade.

Answer (score 3):

A função `Console.WriteLine` escreve e quebra linha.

Neste caso, utilize a função `Console.Write`, que apenas escreve o que você deseja.

Exemplo:

```
Console.Write(numeros[i] + " ");
```

Comment: Oi Bruno, obrigada pela resposta! Tentei com Console.Write e os números saíram todos sem espaçamento entre si, há alguma maneira de corrigir isso?

Comment: Sim, adicione um espaço após `numeros[i] + " "`

Comment: Perfeito, muito obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

Só complementando, é necessário concatenar com mais um espaço, ficando assim:

```
Console.Write(numeros[i] + " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Só por diversão também fiz a minha versão :)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var n)) return;

        var entrada = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

        if (entrada.Length != n)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Entrada deve ter {n} números e foram inseridos {entrada.Length}.");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            var numerosPares = PegaPares(entrada);

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(' ', numerosPares));
            Console.WriteLine(numerosPares.Count());
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> PegaPares(string[] numeros)
    {
        foreach (var numero in numeros)
        {
            if (!int.TryParse(numero, out var valor))
                throw new ArgumentException($"{numero} não é um número.");

            if (valor % 2 == 0)
                yield return valor;
        }
    }
}
```